# Directly call index.php instead of try_files

Tags: php, nginx

I got this construct which works, but is clearly suboptimal.
I tried to follow this guide, https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too, but the configuration for php, is puzzling me. And I fear creating a security problem.
I expected there to be a simple directive, similar to try_files, so it passes everything to index.php.

My version:

```
location / {
    try_files /dev/null /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

If index.php is in first position in try_files, it will deliver the php as download.
I also tried instead of `try_files`, `index index.php`, but then it only works when I load the toplevel domain, e.g. pretty-urls dont work then.

The example from getpagespeed.com

```
location / {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # override SCRIPT_NAME which was set in fastcgi_params
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock;
}
```

Comment: Your question appears to contain the answer. What are you asking?

Comment: Is there not a simpler way, something more straightforward to accomplish what I want?
I understand from your comment, that the solution form getpagespeed is the proper solution?

Comment: There are three perfectly acceptable solutions. Two are listed in your question, and the third is to replace `try_files` with`rewrite ^ /index.php last;` which does the same thing. What is optimum and/or straightforward for you, only you can decide. I suspect that the performance of each solution will be identical unless you are running a massively busy site, in which case you should be testing each of them first.

Comment: Interesting 3. option - thanks you, http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite, so that will then go to the location which matches php - I think, and therefor its not a direct one either.
So I have to learn to properly use the fastcgi params I think.